# Whose responsibility is update to meal preference?

Tags: airlines, food-and-drink

I recently booked a ticket on Delta for a 15+ hour flight through a travel website. Due to dietary restrictions I specifically chose my meal preference in that ticket. This never got updated with Delta, but was visible in the travel website's site. This resulted in no meals of my preference being available on board- which means I had to go hungry for those 15 hours. I contacted the travel website and they said they would research and get back to me, which they haven't. I haven't contacted Delta because it doesn't seem their problem.

What steps can I take so I am compensated for this (if at all I can) ?

Comment: Have you tried talking to delta through Twitter. If they follow the same way of working as klm/airfrance they might be quite communicative. Since the discussion is in the open, discourse is often quite friendly

Comment: While it's too late for you now, I would strongly advise others *never* to trust a third-party site to deliver your booking details completely and accurately. Always confirm contact information, frequent flyer number and status, name spelling, seat assignment, meal preference, and so on directly with the carrier. I learned this long ago when international tickets I had booked for CHOSTER/MR were issued to MRCHOSTER/MR, requiring a tense half hour while the agent figured out how to reissue them without losing my seat, much less my upgrade.

Comment: I would beleive it is the responsibility of the third party. Which country are you in - that will help us answer a bit better. And who was the website, not to name and shame (not that you will mind that) but so we can give you the best answer

Comment: Can you check to see if the meal preference you picked on the third party site is actually one that Delta offers? I could see it going wrong if the booking website has a common list of meal types across all airlines, and no way to check if your airline handles the one you picked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth remembering that Delta agreed to allow this 3rd party website to sell tickets on their behalf.  Therefore, to some degree, it IS Delta's problem as well.

You have two possible options here: blame the third party, or blame Delta.  Or potentially both, as it's a business relationship between them.

I've found in the past when I've had problems with an airline, a simple email to their customer support, explaining what happened, why you were disappointed, and a suggestion that perhaps some compensation would be in order gets a pretty decent response, and I've always been compensated when I've complained about something (to be fair, it has to be bad to make me complain).

If they're failing to respond, I've found you can often get a faster response by tweeting them - something about the message being public suddenly gets a quick response :) Try it with the third party website as well.

Without knowing the workings of the relationship between the third party and Delta, you can't be expected to know exactly who made the error, so I'd try contacting Delta primarily, as they also deserve to know that something went wrong.  If it happens enough, they may change their working relationship.

Good luck!